# Mirroring portion of screen from one area to another (on a single screen)

Tags: user-interface, screen, game-engine, display, mirroring

Is it possible to move skills display for example in league of legends, from skills bar to somewhere closer to the center of screen? This is only for display, dont need that to be clickable. Only to see which skills are on cooldown. The closest solution is this software https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9P2ZTH30XXGL?hl=en-US&gl=US, but it captures only rectangular screen area, which occupies too much screen space. The skill bar is rather "row shape". Does such software even exist? Considering how useful it can be in dota-likes. For example, WOW allows moving skill bar however player wants

i tried this https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9P2ZTH30XXGL?hl=en-US&gl=US